# insertMany unordered/continueOnError in nodejs mongodb driver

Tags: node.js, mongodb, bulkinsert

This works on my local:

```
db.collection('test').insert(docsArray, {ordered: false});
```

> Mongo v2.6.10
>
> NodeJS Driver v2.0.45

But, the same code fails on the server:

> Mongo v2.6.11
>
> NodeJS Driver v2.0.45

I can't comprehend why.

The [driver docs](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#insert) say that `insert` has been depricated in the favor of `insertOne`/`insertMany`/`bulkWrite`. So, I tried using these new functions but to no avail. I want it to silently skip the errors and insert the remaining documents. 
Now, `insertMany` has no unordered inserts and `bulkWrite` has no `insertMany`
What is the official way to do this currently?

Comment: Have you tried `{w: 1, keepGoing: true}` instead of `{ordered: false}`?

Comment: @marekful I just tried that (with both `insert` and `insertMany`). It failed. There are examples in the docs with keepGoing though (for insert).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it:

```
var bulk = db.collection('test').initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
for (var i = 0; i < docs.length; i++) {
   bulk.insert(docs[i]);
};
bulk.execute(function (err, result) {
   db.close();
});
```

Comment: doesn't work for me... using exactly same code.. only 1 record is inserted

Comment: I am using it in production since I figured it out. So I would have to say that you might be missing something, or using it incorrectly.
Please check the error returned from bulk.execute.

Comment: I am using it exactly the same way. However, my error comes on the custom index and not the _id field. I have a unique index setup on user.name field which should be a unique field. Every time i run execute, it always fails after inserting 1 document it if finds a duplicate key.